# First order weak derivatives of $f(x)=|x|^r$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $f(x)=|x|^r$ for a given real number $r$. Show that $f$ has first order weak derivatives on the unit ball $B_1(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ provided that $r > 1-n$.

Does anyone have an idea on how to prove this?

Comment: There's the obvious definition for a weak derivative. Do a change of coordinates to $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates. You may have to split up the integral near 0 and take a limit as epsilon goes to zero.

Comment: see here https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The function is absolutely continuous on almost every line segment (specifically, on every line segment that does not pass through the origin). I.e., it has the ACL property. The partial derivatives are continuous outside of the origin and are homogeneous of degree $r-1 >-n$; therefore, they are integrable.  It is a standard fact that ACL+integrable partials => weak derivatives exist and are represented by the partials (i.e., the function is in the Sobolev class $W^{1,1}$).

There are other approaches. For example, you can take a partition of unity $\phi_n$ subordinate to concentric annuli, so that each $f\phi_n$ is smooth. Then observe that the $W^{1,1}$ norm of $\phi_n f$ decays exponentially as $n\to\infty$ (via rescaling), hence the series converges in $W^{1,1}$.

Comment: @Tomás Don't let me stop you from posting a better answer.